# How to convert String to hex?

Tags: java, android, string, hex, converters

I have a TCP Client running on Android. The Server is an OBD2 Dongle. 
I am getting an InputStream which is saved in a String but it's a hex number.

The Response of the TCP Server looks like that: FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20
It is a 8byte long hex number but I it is sent as a String, so I need to convert it to hex.

How can I do that?

Edit:

```
InputStream is; 

is = socket.getInputStream(); 

while(var_Receive){

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is); 

String line = rd.readLine(); 

System.out.prinln(line); 

}
```

And this is exactly what I see on screnn 'FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20' including the spaces between.

Comment: `How to convert String to hex?`. Wrong question. You have alredy a hex string. You want to convert it to long. Please adapt your post.

Comment: So you have String hexString = "FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20`; Why these spaces in between? I would rather think you have String hexString = "FDA8F1FF1FD00320";

Comment: I am getting an InputStream which is saved in a String`. One would read `bytes` from an input stream to begin with. So if you end up with a string you made a string out of them. So please tell exactly what you receive.

Comment: @greenapps I have  

public InputStream is;

is = socket.getInputStream();

while(var_Receive){
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is);
String line = rd.readLine()
System.out.prinln(line);
}

And this is exactly what I see on screnn 'FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20' including the spaces between.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String));

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will work. The value printed in console is in hexadecimal format. Store it if you want to use it later.

```
public static void stringToHex(){

    String hexStr = "FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20";
    char[] chars = hexStr.toCharArray();

      StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
      hex = new StringBuffer("0x");
      int  i =0;
      while(i<chars.length){
          if(chars[i]==' '){
              i++;
              //you can store this value if you want
              System.out.println(hex.toString());
              hex = new StringBuffer("0x");
              continue;
          }
          hex.append(chars[i]);
          i++;
      }
}
```

Shorter implementation according to requirement:

```
String hexStr = "FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20";
String[] hexStrs = hexStr.split(" ");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
Double[] values = new Double[hexStrs.length];
for(int i=0; i<hexStrs.length; i++){
    values[i] = Double.valueOf(df.format(Integer.valueOf(hexStrs[i], 16)*0.04));
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

Comment: ????? I wonder what works. And where is the conversion to long? The input was hex already.

Comment: Hi greenapps, actually Mike wanted FD in form of 0xFD so I just appended that string. It could have been shorter using split() function of String.

Comment: @greenapps can You give an example for conversion?

Comment: "hexStr" is the String input. Example using spli() `String[] hexStrs = hexStr.split(" ");
     for(String str : hexStrs)
      System.out.println("0x"+str);`

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I maybe I could not express myself. At the end I Need the single or multiple Bytes in a double. For Example: The second Byte 'A8' delivers informations about pressure in an engine. Hex A8 is a decimal 168. The conversion rate for calculating the pressure is 0.04 bar/bit. So I have to calculate 168 * 0.04 = 6.72 bar. This is what I'm trying to do :(

Comment: It can be done (variables are equals to as define in previous comment). DecimalFormat helps in determining the number after decimal point.  `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
     for(String str : hexStrs)
      System.out.println(df.format(Integer.valueOf(str, 16)*0.04));`

Comment: @Mike edited the answer according to your requirement. Does it help?

Comment: That works, also the calculating is correct. But I have to save the value before multiplying with 0.04 somewhere but I am not sure which is the best way...

Comment: In place of printing it to console store the value `df.format(Integer.valueOf(str, 16)` in some array and use whenever required by iterating over that array.

Comment: With decimalformat it's still a string, right? I think it would be better to convert to double to completly go away from strings after getting the inputstream. You helped me a lot, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Do the values in the hex representation represent a single value? If so:

```
String hexStr = "FD A8 F1 FF 1F D0 03 20";
String hexNoSpace = hexStr.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

long valAsLong = long.Parse(hexNoSpace, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
ulong valAsUnsignedLong = ulong.Parse(hexNoSpace, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

result:

as long: -168618907973713120

as ulong: 18278125165735838496